# Run intellij IDEA plugin from Main method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins

I want to force developers to run findbugs plugin for their business class before commit them . now want solution to run findbugs plugin from code but I cannot find any solution to access intellij idea plugin from code.
Can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to run the findbugs IntelliJ IDEA plugin from your main() method, because IntelliJ IDEA plugins can only run in an IntelliJ IDEA instance.

However, findbugs is also available as a standalone tool, which you can very easily run from the command line, as described in [the documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html).